# Is there a way to add a PWA to Home Screen in the Test-Run Setup and Remove it from Home Screen in the Test-Run Teardown

Tags: progressive-web-apps, homescreen, autotest

I am developing a PWA from scratch, using TDD approach. I also need PWA to be added to Home Screen in order to be able to use the https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/ API. In order to be able to isolate each test-run (not having to worry about previous test-run's service worker instance to get in the way) it seems logical to start each test run with adding the PWA being developed to the Home Screen and finish the test-run with removing the PWA from the Home Screen. 
Is there a way to do that automatically? For example, using Appium?
Is there an example of doing this?

Comment: The user needs to explicitly agree to the install by pressing the button. So perhaps if you have a testing tool that can automatically press on that button, perhaps.

Comment: Had to do it myself: https://github.com/istolboff/rmwiaa/tree/master/PwaHomeScreenUtilities
Used Appium in order to simulate user adding/removing PWA from the browser's GUI